# Android statusbar code deprecated

Tags: android, notifications, statusbar

Hi mates i'm trying to develop an app which needs to send a notification for the user at certain time. In the internet i found this code but eclipse says that it's deprecated.
Do you know which is the proper way to do it with my API? (16)

```
NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

int icon = R.drawable.worldmap2;
CharSequence tickerText = "Hello";
long when = System.currentTimeMillis();
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText,when);
Context context = getApplicationContext();
CharSequence contentTitle = "My notification";
CharSequence contentText = "Hello World!";
final Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HttpExampleLimits.class);
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent1, 0);
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, contentTitle,contentText, pIntent);


nm.notify(1, notification);
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve it is to use Support library and `NotificationCompat` class.

You can find a lot of examples on offical doc: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html